# Prove that the sequence $C_{n+1} = 1 + \frac{C_n}{C_n + 1}$ is monotonically increasing by induction

Tags: limits, induction, recursive-algorithms, monotone-functions

I have a sequence

$$C_{n+1}  = 1 + \frac{C_n}{C_n + 1}$$

With a base case $C_1 = 3/2$ and want to prove that it's monotonically increasing by induction.

Whenever I try to prove $C_n < C_{n+1} \implies C_{n+1} < C_{n+2}$

where $$C_{n+2} = 1 + \frac{2C_n + 1}{3C_n + 2} $$

I get to the inequality $$ \frac{C_n}{C_n + 1} < \frac{2C_n + 1}{(C_n + 1)^2} $$

but don't know how to get to the point where that implies that $C_{n+1} < C_{n+2}$

Thank

Comment: You don't need to get into $C_{n+2}$, try to prove $C_n > 1 + \frac{C_n}{1 + C_n}$ and you'll also need to prove $C_n > R$ for some minimum value $R$ at the same time.

Comment: Compute $$C_{n+1}-C_n$$

Comment: @DanielV:  I think you meant $C_n\color{red}<1+\frac{C_n}{1+C_n}=C_{n+1}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes you are right thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As $C_1=\frac 32$, it is clear that every consecutive term $C_2, C_3, \dots, C_n$ is positive as $C_{n+1}$ is the sum of two positive terms for all $n>0$. We have

\begin{align}C_{n+2}-C_{n+1}&=\Big(1 + \frac{C_{n+1}}{C_{n+1} + 1}\Big) - \Big(1- \frac{C_n}{C_n + 1}\Big)\\&=
\Big(1 + \frac{1 + \frac{C_n}{C_n + 1}}{2 + \frac{C_n}{C_n + 1}}\Big) - \Big(1- \frac{C_n}{C_n + 1}\Big)\\&=
\Big(1 + \frac{2C_n+1}{3C_n+2}\Big) - \Big(1- \frac{C_n}{C_n + 1}\Big)\\&=
\frac{2C_n+1}{3C_n+2}+\frac{C_n}{C_n + 1}\\&>0
\end{align}

which shows that $C_{n+2}>C_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 2):

rewrite as $$C_{n+1}  = 1 + \frac{C_n}{C_n + 1}= \frac{2C_n+1}{C_n + 1}=2-\frac{1}{1+C_n}$$
now
$$C_{n+2}  -C_{n+1}=2-\frac{1}{1+C_{n+1}}-(2-\frac{1}{1+C_{n}})=\\
\frac{1}{1+C_{n}}-\frac{1}{1+C_{n+1}}=
\\\frac{1+C_{n+1}-(1+C_{n})}{(1+C_{n+1})(1+C_{n})}=\\
\frac{C_{n+1}-C_{n}}{(1+C_{n+1})(1+C_{n})}=$$so now you can build your induction
$$ C_{n+1}>C_n \implies C_{n+2} > C_{n+1}$$because 
$$C_{n+2}  -C_{n+1}=\frac{C_{n+1}-C_{n}}{(1+C_{n+1})(1+C_{n})}=\frac{C_{n+1}-C_{n}}{(positive)(positive)}$$

Answer (score 1):

By induction, it is clear that $C_n>0$ for all $n$. Put $c=C_n$.

You want : $C_{n+1}\gt C_n$, which is equivalent to

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
C_{n+1}\gt C_n & \Leftrightarrow & 1+\frac{C_n}{C_n+1} \gt C_n \\
  & \Leftrightarrow & 1+\frac{c}{1+c} \gt c \\
  & \Leftrightarrow & \frac{1+2c}{1+c} \gt c \\
  & \Leftrightarrow & 1+2c \gt c+c^2 \\
  & \Leftrightarrow & 0 \gt -1-c+c^2 \\
  & \Leftrightarrow & 0 \gt \big(c-\frac{1}{2}\big)^2-\frac{5}{4}\\
  & \Leftrightarrow & \frac{5}{4} \gt \big(c-\frac{1}{2}\big)^2\\
  & \Leftrightarrow & \frac{-\sqrt{5}}{2} \lt c-\frac{1}{2} \lt \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\\
  & \Leftrightarrow & \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2} \lt c \lt \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\\
\end{array}
$$

Put $\alpha=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\beta=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.
So, the goal is now to show that $\alpha \lt C_n \lt \beta$ for every $n$.

Can you finish from here ? (use induction and $C_{n+1}=2-\frac{1}{1+C_n}$).

Comment: Why $C_{n+1} = 1 + \frac{1}{C_n}$?

Comment: That was a typo, it's corrected now, sorry

Comment: $C_{n+1}=1+\frac{C_n}{1+C_n}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner sure, but $1+\frac{C_n}{1+C_n}$ is the same thing as $2-\frac{1}{1+C_n}$

Comment: Ok, you must have edited to that around the same time I made my comment

Comment: I understand the logic and know what it's bounded by but I'm not sure how to then prove that it's bounded since it's a recursive sequence

Comment: @johnsmith It goes as follows : if you have bounds on $C_n$, deduce bounds on $1+C_n$, then bounds of $\frac{1}{1+C_n}$, then bounds on $\frac{-1}{1+C_n}$ etc up to bounds on $C_{n+1}=2-\frac{1}{1+C_n}$

Answer (score 1):

Or you can set $f(x)=1+\dfrac{x}{x+1}$. Using the derivative prove that $f'>0$ and so $f$ is strictly increasing. Then apply $f$ to the induction hypothesis: suppose $C_{n}>C_{n-1}$, then 
$f(C_{n})>f(C_{n-1})$ because $f$ is increasing. Then conclude...

Answer (score 0):

Or you can set $f(x)=1+\dfrac{x}{x+1}$. Using the derivative prove that $f'>0$ and so $f$ is strictly increasing. Then apply $f$ to the induction hypothesis: suppose $C_{n}> C_{n-1}$, then 
$f(C_{n})> f(C_{n-1})$ because $f$ is increasing. Then conclude...

Comment: this appears to be a copy of another answer with a mistake

Answer (score 0):

If $C_n\ge0$, then obviously $C_{n+1}\ge 1$. Furthermore, note that with $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$, the [Golden Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio),
$$
\begin{align}
C_{n+1}-\phi
&=1-\phi+\frac{C_n}{C_n+1}\\
&=-\frac1\phi+\frac{C_n}{C_n+1}\\
&=\frac{(\phi-1)C_n-1}{\phi(C_n+1)}\\
&=\frac{C_n-\phi}{\phi^2(C_n+1)}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, if $C_1\lt\phi$, then $C_n\lt\phi$ and $C_{n+1}\gt C_n$ for $n\ge1$.
Also, if $C_1\gt\phi$, then $C_n\gt\phi$ and $C_{n+1}\lt C_n$ for $n\ge1$.

If $C_1=\frac32\lt\phi$, then $C_n\lt\phi$ and $C_{n+1}\gt C_n$ for $n\ge1$ (increasing and bounded above).